# Rails | show url parameters on show page after create

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I added the URL parameters to the new.html.erb page by a link_to

```
<%= link_to 'Message', new_personal_message_path(receiver_id: 1010) %>
```

which correctly to displayed in the URL as

> example.com/personal_messages/new?receiver_id=1010

and i was able to than reference it in my controller by simple `@receiver = User.find_by(id: params[:receiver_id])`

---

On the new.html.erb i have this form to create a new conversation:

```
<%= form_for @personal_message do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'receiver_id', @receiver.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: "personal_message_textarea", placeholder: "Chat with us...", :autofocus => true %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :conversation_id, params[:id] || session[:conversation_id] %>
  <%= f.submit " ", placeholder: "Chat with us!", class: "personal_message_submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And it'll automatically redirect the user to the show page which the url displays as

> example.com/conversations/1

But I also want it to also show the newly created user_id (I have a method in my controllers that automatically creates a user account on create) in the URL parameters like so:

> example.com/conversatinos/1?user_id=23&receiver_id=1010

the new method in personal_messages controller

```
def new
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation) and return if @conversation
    @personal_message = PersonalMessage.new
    @site = Site.find_by(id: cookies[:siteid]) #used to pull site description
end
```

create method in personal_messages controller

```
  def create
    @conversation ||= Conversation.create(author_id: cookies[:user_id],
                                         receiver_id: @receiver.id)
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build(personal_message_params)
    @personal_message.conversation_id = @conversation.id
    @personal_message.save!
    flash[:success] = "ok!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation)
  end
```

Comment: where do you get the `user_id` and `receiver_id` from?

Answer (score 0):

fixed: personal_messages controllers

```
  def create
    @conversation ||= Conversation.create(author_id: cookies[:user_id],
                                         receiver_id: @receiver.id)
    @personal_message = current_user.personal_messages.build(personal_message_params)
    @personal_message.conversation_id = @conversation.id
    @personal_message.save!
    flash[:success] = "ok!"
    #redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation)
    redirect_to conversation_path(@conversation, user_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: @receiver)
  end
```